# "This field is required." Django rest framework

Tags: django, post, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I 've created an API with django rest framework with some measurements . I am trying to post a TreeSensor measurement through postman or django API. Weather measurements works fine but on my TreeSensor I get the following error even though they are identical besides the fields.

```
{
    "soil_moisture_depth_1": [
        "This field is required."
    ],
    "soil_moisture_depth_2": [
        "This field is required."
    ]  }
```

Serializers :

```
class TreeSensorMeasurementSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TreeSensorMeasurement
        fields = ["sensor", "datetime", "soil_moisture_depth_1","soil_moisture_depth_2","soil_moisture_depth_1_filtered","soil_moisture_depth_2_filtered", "soil_temperature"]

class WeatherStationMeasurementSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta: 
        model = WeatherStationMeasurement
        fields = ["sensor", "datetime", "wind_speed", "current_rain", "wind_direction", "solar_radiation", "air_temperature", "air_humidity", "air_pressure", "luminosity", "battery", "dew_point"]
```

API :

```
    ########### TreeSensorMeasurement Api ###########
    def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs):

        data = {
            'sensor' : request.data.get('sensor'),
            'datetime' : request.data.get('datetime'),
            'soi_moisture_depth_1' : request.data.get('soil_moisture_depth_1'),
            'soi_moisture_depth_2' : request.data.get('soil_moisture_depth_2'),
            'soi_moisture_depth_1_filtered' : request.data.get('soil_moisture_depth_1_filtered'),
            'soi_moisture_depth_2_filtered' : request.data.get('soil_moisture_depth_2_filtered'),
            'soil_temperature' : request.data.get('soil_temperature'),
        }
        serializer = TreeSensorMeasurementSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

    ########### WeatherStationMeasurement Api ###########
    def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs):

        data = {
            'sensor' : request.data.get('sensor'),
            'datetime' : request.data.get('datetime'),
            'wind_speed' : request.data.get('wind_speed'),
            'current_rain' : request.data.get('current_rain'),
            'wind_direction' : request.data.get('wind_direction'),
            'solar_radiation' : request.data.get('solar_radiation'),
            'air_temperature' : request.data.get('air_temperature'),
            'air_humidity' : request.data.get('air_humidity'),
            'air_pressure' : request.data.get('air_pressure'),
            'luminosity' : request.data.get('luminosity'),
            'battery' : request.data.get('battery'),
            'dew_point' : request.data.get('dew_point'),     
        }
        serializer = WeatherStationMeasurementSerializer(data=data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error occurred because you had changed the field names.

```
########### TreeSensorMeasurement Api ###########
def post(self,request, *args, **kwargs):

    data = {
        'sensor' : request.data.get('sensor'),
        'datetime' : request.data.get('datetime'),
        # Here I changed the field names
        'soil_moisture_depth_1' : request.data.get('soil_moisture_depth_1'),
        'soil_moisture_depth_2' : request.data.get('soil_moisture_depth_2'),
        'soil_moisture_depth_1_filtered' : request.data.get('soil_moisture_depth_1_filtered'),
        'soil_moisture_depth_2_filtered' : request.data.get('soil_moisture_depth_2_filtered'),
        'soil_temperature' : request.data.get('soil_temperature'),
    }
    serializer = TreeSensorMeasurementSerializer(data=data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

The `soi_...` field names should be changed into `soil_...`.

Comment: Damn.. THANKS a a lot . Im busting my head for so long and its just a typo....  I just couldnt notice. I'll try to be more careful . thanks again for pointing it out .